# Dask Dataframe: Get row count?

Tags: python, dataframe, dask

Simple question: I have a dataframe in dask containing about 300 mln records. I need to know the exact number of rows that the dataframe contains. Is there an easy way to do this?

When I try to run `dataframe.x.count().compute()` it looks like it tries to load the entire data into RAM, for which there is no space and it crashes.

Comment: The use of count() doesn't seem appropriate here. Try len(df) instead.

Comment: Using len(df) also tries to load the entire dataset into memory for some reason. Is that normal? Did I set up my dataframe wrong? All the data is read from a single hdf5 file, by the way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How should I get the shape of a dask dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50355598/how-should-i-get-the-shape-of-a-dask-dataframe)

Comment: I got the same issue, my solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56835689/3784537

Answer (score 14):

```
# ensure small enough block size for the graph to fit in your memory
ddf = dask.dataframe.read_csv('*.csv', blocksize="10MB") 
ddf.shape[0].compute()
```

From the [documentation](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/generated/dask.dataframe.read_csv.html#dask.dataframe.read_csv):

> blocksize <str, int or None>
> Optional Number of bytes by which to cut up
> larger files. Default value is computed based on available physical
> memory and the number of cores, up to a maximum of 64MB. Can be a
> number like 64000000` or a string like ``"64MB". If None, a single
> block is used for each file.

Answer (score 1):

If you only need the number of rows -
you can load a subset of the columns while selecting the columns with lower memory usage (such as category/integers and not string/object), there after you can run `len(df.index)`