# How should I get the shape of a dask dataframe?

Tags: python, dask

Performing .shape is giving me the following error.

> AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'shape'

How should I get the shape instead?

Answer (score 37):

You can get the number of columns directly

```
len(df.columns)  # this is fast
```

You can also call len on the dataframe itself, though beware that this will trigger a computation.

```
len(df)  # this requires a full scan of the data
```

Dask.dataframe doesn't know how many records are in your data without first reading through all of it.

Comment: len(df) is loading all of the records and in my case, finding len(df) for a table at size 144M rows took more than few minutes (wind10,ram16,intel7). Any other way?

Comment: It probably has to load all of the data to find out the length.  No, there is no other way.  You could consider using something like a database, which tracks this sort of information in metadata.

Comment: i've been doing `df.index.size.compute()` which is faster than running `len(df)` ... but my data is stored in columnar parquet... so it depends on what your underlying data architecture is.

Answer (score 28):

With shape you can do the following

```
a = df.shape
a[0].compute(),a[1]
```

This will shop the shape just as it is shown with pandas

Answer (score 7):

Well, I know this is a quite old question, but I had the same issue and I got an out-of-the-box solution which I just want to register here.

Considering your data, I'm wondering that it is originally saved in a CSV similar file; so, for my situation, I just count the lines of that file (minus one, the header line). Inspired by [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27518377/3784537), this is the solution I'm using:

```py
import dask.dataframe as dd
from itertools import (takewhile,repeat)
 
def rawincount(filename):
    f = open(filename, 'rb')
    bufgen = takewhile(lambda x: x, (f.raw.read(1024*1024) for _ in repeat(None)))
    return sum( buf.count(b'\n') for buf in bufgen )

filename = 'myHugeDataframe.csv'
df = dd.read_csv(filename)
df_shape = (rawincount(filename) - 1, len(df.columns))
print(f"Shape: {df_shape}")
```

Hope this could help someone else as well.

Comment: This approach is very fast and take an advantage of distributed processing in dask

Comment: Thank you! This is faster than the other possible solution of loading a single columns and obtaining its length.

Answer (score 3):

```py
print('(',len(df),',',len(df.columns),')')
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the shape we can try this way:

```
 dask_dataframe.describe().compute()
```

"count" column of the index will give the number of rows

```
 len(dask_dataframe.columns)
```

this will give the number of columns in the dataframe

Answer (score -2):

Getting number of columns by below code.

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
dd1=dd.read_csv("filename.txt")
print(dd1.info)

#Output
<class 'dask.dataframe.core.DataFrame'>
Columns: 6 entries, CountryName to Value
dtypes: object(4), float64(1), int64(1)
```

Comment: in Pandas, shape will output both number of rows and columns. I don't think showing number of columns answers OP's question.

Comment: Columns: 6 entries 
What is this in output and i am using dask FYI.