# Why doesn't Dask dataframe have a shape attribute?

Tags: python, dataframe, dask

Just out of curiosity, if dask enables both len() and size, why is there not shape as well?

Comment: This may be a design choice or an oversight. Unless you can catch the guy wrote the library, you are likely to only find opinions here (not too helpful).

Comment: @jpp The guy who wrote it is really active on SO.

Comment: @user32185, Yup, I know, he's really helpful too, which is why I commented :).

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50355598/how-should-i-get-the-shape-of-a-dask-dataframe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been discussed in dask. First I'll point out that in the python spec, `len()` is always supposed to return a concrete integer. Dask respects this, and so `len(df)` blocks, unlike most operations on a data-frame. There is no such constraint on `.size`, which is therefore lazy.

The metadata of the dataframe is immediately available, however, the number, names and types of the columns are known without computing any of the data. Therefore, `.shape` would be a combination of a known value and either a lazy or a slowly-computed concrete value. This doesn't seem necessary.